# Move main activity logout button event to a another tab fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

I want to move the following welcome label and logout button to the tab_profile fragment, right now it's visible in all 4 tabs which i created after successful login

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/lbl_name"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
        android:text="@string/btn_logout"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### MainAtivity.java

```
package gira.cdap.com.giira;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import gira.cdap.com.giira.activity.LoginActivity;
import gira.cdap.com.giira.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import gira.cdap.com.giira.helper.SessionManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView txtName;
    private TextView txtEmail;
    private Button btnLogout;

    private SQLiteHandler db;
    private SessionManager session;

    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.tour,
            R.drawable.event,
            R.drawable.profile
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(tabIcons[0]));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(tabIcons[1]));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(tabIcons[2]));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(tabIcons[3]));
                tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
     * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
     * */
    private void logoutUser() {
        session.setLogin(false);

        db.deleteUsers();

        // Launching the login activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

### tab_profile.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="tab_profile"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

### ProfileActivity.java

```
package gira.cdap.com.giira.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import gira.cdap.com.giira.R;


public class ProfileActivity extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_profile, container, false);

    }
}
```

### PagerAdapter.java

```
package gira.cdap.com.giira;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import gira.cdap.com.giira.activity.EventActivity;
import gira.cdap.com.giira.activity.HomeActivity;
import gira.cdap.com.giira.activity.ProfileActivity;
import gira.cdap.com.giira.activity.TourActivity;

/**
 * Created by Muqshid on 5/10/2016.
 */
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                HomeActivity tab1 = new HomeActivity();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TourActivity tab2 = new TourActivity();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                EventActivity tab3 = new EventActivity();
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                ProfileActivity tab4 = new ProfileActivity();
                return tab4;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the position of the buttons should not change and you don´t want them to scroll within the viewpager just hide and show them depending on the current active page

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand of your succinct problem, just cut/paste the following:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
        android:text="@string/btn_logout"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
```

In the tab_profile.xml, and you will be good! That's the file you have to work on to personalize your fragment.

Comment: yes i did tried 

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

im getting the following Null object reference error

Comment: I will need the part of code where you are calling the setText method, because you're calling it on an uninstantiated TextView.

Comment: these are the tutorials that i followed

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

http://www.android4devs.com/2015/12/tab-layout-material-design-support.html